# Can funding children's college education be mandated during divorce?

Tags: new-york-state, divorce, new-jersey

If a married couple are divorcing, can the judge mandate that one of the spouses fund the children's college education (if the details matter, let's say the children are teenagers but not of college age yet OR, they are in college but under 18).

I am asking about funding mandated **on top** of "normal" division of assets that would happen if, for example, the children were not planning to attend college at all. Not some negotiated thing where "I pay $X for kids college but the asset division claims against me are reduced by $Y in return".

If jurisdiction makes a difference, let's say New Jersey or New York states.

Comment: In Canada, university expenses can explicitly be made part of the divorce decree.  [See this question.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44842/do-parents-have-an-obligation-to-pay-for-university-expenses-after-divorce)

Comment: I can't say specifically about NY or NJ, but I am aware of at least two cases where the agreement between the divorcing parties included one parent funding a trust to cover college expenses.  I don't believe the judge mandated either one but it was a negotiating point in the agreements.

Comment: In New Jersey there is actually [state Supreme Court precedent](https://www.njlawblog.com/2006/11/articles/divorce/divorced-parents-responsibility-to-fund-higher-education-expenses/) that divorced parents have an obligation to help fund their children's education, so I would certainly expect such arrangements to be anticipated in divorce decrees.

Comment: @jwh20 - the question explicitly excludes the case of mutual agreement - the whole point is, can a judge impose that if a party doesn't agree to it

Comment: @CuriousGeorge That happens all the time.

Comment: It is often done by mutual agreement in a separation agreement ratified by the judge, I'll have to research more to answer the question of whether the judge can mandate it, however. There is quite a bit of interstate variation on this issue. apparently in NJ it is allowed per another comment.